# Why do different countries/regions have different methods of counting large numbers?

Tags: soft-question, math-history

When we start counting large quantities of $10's$, the number system varies by country/region:

- Europe/US: $10^3$ (thousand, million, billion are all multiples of $10^3$)
- Japan/China/Korea: $10^4$ (万, 億, 兆 are all multiples of $10^4$)
- India: $10^5$ (lakh), $10^8$ (crore = $100$ lakh)

In the 1600s, Japan used [different groupings](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16243/3300), and Europe used/uses [the long scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales#History). I am sure there are others I am not aware of.

As someone who has worked with different number systems, it is incredibly difficult to process large numbers if you are used to counting by $10^3$, and have to read written numbers that are based on $10^4$ (while not a perfect analogy, it requires conscious thought like switching from base $10$ to base $8$ or the like).

If [Wikipedia is to be believed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system) mathematical concepts for numerals were shared across regions. We all use base $10$, for instance. Given that these systems do change with time within a single country, why hasn't there been any unification between countries to formalize how many decimal places to group larger numbers by?

Comment: We use base 10 because we have 10 fingers, and that's the first method we can count thing. With our fingers. Moreover, it could be the case that we developed the notions of counting small amounts tens of thousands of years ago, but the concepts of large numbers began to rise only after civilizations began to take shape. This would explain why everyone counts the same with small numbers, but large numbers are handled differently. Of course, these are just idle speculations without any real research that I've done on the topic.

Comment: And computer uses base 2 is simply because it only has 2 fingers, namely ON and OFF. *JOKE :D

Comment: @Asaf, we also have 20 fingers + toes, and many languages use twenties as a counter (score = 20, the French for 80 is 4 x 20, etc.). We also have 5 fingers on a hand. Yes, 10 is convenient, but that all regions in the world use base 10 cannot solely be because we all have 10 fingers. Why are we so consistent on that point, but not this one? Is there some historical reasoning for this?

Comment: "We all use base 10, for instance" ... it is not so evident that it **must** be so. See Karl Menninger, [Number Words and Number Symbols: A Cultural History of Numbers](http://www.amazon.com/Number-Words-Symbols-Cultural-History/dp/0486270963/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1400849328&sr=1-1&keywords=karl+menninger+number) (1969 - Dover reprint)

Answer (score 2):

For what's worth, even the same language, like English, had two counting systems, since the British, just like the rest of Europeans, used the [long scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales) $($million, milliard, billion, billiard, trillion, trilliard, quadrillion, quadrilliard, quintillion, quintilliard, etc$)$, whereas the Americans use the [short scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales) $($million, billion, trillion, quadrillion, quintillion, etc$)$. Secondly, the use of myriads $($ tens of thousands$)$ is customary in Greek. Not to mention that dozens and gross were used up until not too long ago in human history, since they divide so nicely into the customary fractions: halves, thirds, and quarters.

Comment: Not to mention the binary system of volumes used in Britain...

Comment: Outdated.  The UK government adopted the short scale in 1974.  Nowadays, even the *Times* of London uses "billion" with the American meaning $10^9$.

Comment: However, most of continental Europe use the long scale.